# Wordpress счетчик постов в произвольных таксономиях

Tags: php, wordpress

Как вывести количество опубликованных постов произвольного типа в текущей таксономии, тоже кастомной? С проверкой на таксономию, то есть, чтобы был один код для всех.

Я понимаю, что и как должно работать, но вот написать не могу сам.
Согласно [справочнику](http://wp-kama.ru/functions) :

```
$count_posts = wp_count_posts('post');
$published_posts = $count_posts->publish;
```

получает количество опубликованных постов заданного типа `'post'` во всех категориях. и Еще из [интернета](http://yournet.kz/blog/wp/kolichestvo-zapisey-v-kategorii-wordpress):

```
echo get_category($ID)->category_count;
```

выводит количество опубликованных постов в категории, в теории, должно было сработать что-то типа `echo get_taxonomy($name)->category_count;`, но нет

Answer (score 1):

> Как вывести количество опубликованных постов произвольного типа в текущей таксономии, тоже кастомной?

[wp_count_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_count_terms/) или [get_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) или [wp_count_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_posts).

> получает количество опубликованных постов заданного типа 'post' во всех категориях.

Нужно передавать значения:

`$published_posts = wp_count_posts('new_post_type')->publish;`

Comment: этот код выведет количество ВСЕХ опубликованных записей. Как оставить только те записи, которые находятся в текущей категории?

Comment: хм..да. Похоже поможет http://wp-kama.ru/function/get_term

Comment: можете написать, как будет выглядеть конечный вариант?